# Ido mode is too smart, can I get it to NOT complete a filename?

Tags: emacs, ido-mode

My problem: I have Ido-mode enabled and I want to edit (for example) a file `.emacs` in my home directory. I have no `.emacs` file there, but I do have a `.emacs.d`, and so ido assumes that I want to enter the directory when I do `C-x C-f .emacs RET`.

I've been trying to solve this for at least weeks, and I've got a couple work-arounds but I would really rather not have to do anything crazy.

Comment: Thank god somebody asked this. It was driving me nuts. Thanks!

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You can either press `C-j` to accept what you have typed so far, or `C-f` which will drop you into regular find-file

Comment: holy cow I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Comment: If several files/dirs have common parts of the name by pressing C-s or C-r you cycle through file list forward or backward.

Comment: This also allows to skip optional arguments for commands like `LaTeX-environment`. Extremely useful for tables. Thanks!

Comment: I know this question is old, but just to add, you can press ctrl-z while in ido mode to disable its auto-completion.

Comment: With icomplete + fido this is `M-j`.