# Emacs ido-mode and creating new files in directories, it keeps changing the directory while I'm typing

Tags: emacs, ido-mode

When using ido-mode in emacs, it tends to get in my way when I'm trying to create a new file inside a directory, using: <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-f</kbd> ( start typing a new filename, which doesn't yet exist ) <kbd>RET</kbd>

Ordinarily this should create a new file, but when I have ido mode, I have to type the new filename really quickly, otherwise ido-mode decides to move me into a directory that has a file with a matching name, causing me to open that file, instead of creating a new file.

Does anybody know how to force ido-mode to avoid looking in directories other than the one you're currently in?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can disable the merging (the "looking in other directories" in ido vulgo) with

```
(setq ido-auto-merge-work-directories-length -1)
```

but you can also undo the merge with `C-z` in ido.

Comment: Right you are :) I would not have guessed the purpose from the name of that function. Works perfectly.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't clear what the heck "merge" meant in the `ido` context until I found this answer.

Comment: `C-z` gets me what I need (I was having the exact same problem); thanks!  This way I can keep the behavior (it's convenient, *sometimes*), but still have a way to get out of it when it's not what I want (most of the time).

Comment: "it's convenient, sometimes" you can also disable it and trigger the merge using M-s if that is what you would prefer (I do).

Answer (score 27):

Doing this really helps.  Basically use ido-mode up until you get to the correct directory, then hit <kbd>C-f</kbd> again to get out of ido-mode as you type the new filename.

<kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-f</kbd> *navigate to directory* <kbd>C-f</kbd> *enter new filename* <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Comment: I have a feeling this should have more up-votes than the other answer. thx

Answer (score 4):

Use <kbd>C-j</kbd> to [tell ido to input what you have typed](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/ido.el#n85) rather than the first completion.  This is also [mentioned](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InteractivelyDoThings) on emacswiki.

Comment: This only works if you've finished typing the filename before it switches directory.  If I've stalled halfway through typing a filename, it switches directory, then when I carry on typing, it's just matching files in some other part of my home directory.

Comment: Hmm, actually, just double typing <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-f</kbd> <kbd>C-f</kbd> if my plan is to create a new file seems to help, since that jumps out of ido mode.  It's not perfect, but it's better than it changing directory.