# arch linux emacs minibuffer autocompletion

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, archlinux

I recently installed Arch, and the version of emacs that it has comes with an aggressive auto-completion feature that doesn't let me create a new file.  It is also very annoying.  How do I get rid of it?

Comment: The last time I used Arch it had a perfectly regular GNU Emacs. This makes sense since [one of Arch's design goals](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Linux#Simplicity) is that it "ships software as released by the original developers (upstream) with minimal distribution-specific (downstream) changes". You'll have to be a lot more specific about what you are seeing.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/812809/113848) solve the problem? My guess is that Arch enables `ido-mode` by default.

Comment: Yes, ido-mode was it.  One can toggle it off with alt-x ido-mode, or set it to off in .emacs with (ido-mode nil).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have Archlinux too, but it didn't come with emacs. I think that you have installed this module: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete

Check it, and if this is the case, uninstall the addition.